# Heroku admin page not found

Tags: django, heroku

I've deployed a cookie cutter django app. It runs fine. But I can t access to admin  I create a superuser and it connect fine. But I ve a 404 not found when I try to go to admin page

To know urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Needed for locale change
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path("", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="pages/home.html"), name="home"),
    path(
        "about/", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="pages/about.html"), name="about"
    ),
    # Django Admin, use {% url 'admin:index' %}
    path(settings.ADMIN_URL, admin.site.urls),
    # User management
    path("users/", include("gusta.users.urls", namespace="users")),
    path("accounts/", include("allauth.urls")),
    # Your stuff: custom urls includes go here
    path("employee/", include("gusta.employee.urls")),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In heroku logs:nothing

In my local app I can access to it without issue.
Some clues ?

Answer (score 0):

find out: I create a DJANGO_ADMIN_URL var